# Sort Arrays in MongoDB shell - using $sort

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, shell, sorting

I am trying to sort arrays in MongoDB shell.

This seems to be the only syntax available to use.

```js
db.products.updateOne({"name": "ben"}, {$push: {"hobbies": {$each: [], $sort: -1}}})
```

My question is that, is there no other way to do this - in MongoDB, do I have to use th **$push** operator - as I am not doing a push operation.

Comment: From the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#mongodb-update-up.-sort), yes you can pass the empty array. Just you need to provide the field to be sorted for `$sort`, example: `$sort: { "<your field>": <sort order> } `. Otherwise, if you want to grab the data with the array element in sort order, you can use [`$sortArray`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/) in the aggregation query.

Comment: Did you try [$sortArray](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/#-sortarray--aggregation-)?

Comment: please can you write a syntax as an example. I do not like the aggregation pipeline. please do not show me.

Comment: What do you mean by "I do not like the aggregation pipeline"? What's wrong with it?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit It feels to cumbersome. liking trying to use a nuclear weapon to hit a small rock.

Comment: Hi @neil, the link I shared in the comment provides the example to sort array that is either array of documents or non-documents. I am not sure whether should I write it as an answer as it will be copied from the documentation. Meanwhile, using `$sortArray` with aggregation query is another choice that you just want the data in projection, without modifying existing documents.

Comment: @YongShun please write the answer. I am too dumb to know what to use.

Comment: What is your problem? You found a working solution by yourself, but you don't want neither `$push` nor an aggregation pipeline. - **Why?**

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand your antipathy against aggregation pipelines, it would be a simple

```
db.products.updateOne(
   { name: "ben" },
   [{ $set: { hobbies: { $sortArray: { input: "$hobbies", sortBy: -1 } } } }]
)
```

Answer (score 3):

As per requested, you can provide the empty array in the [`$push`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#mongodb-update-up.-sort) operator to perform sorting the element in the array.

> To use the `$sort` modifier, it must appear with the $each modifier. You can pass an empty array `[]` to the $each modifier such that only the `$sort` modifier has an effect.

When your elements in the array to be sorted are [non-documents](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#sort-array-elements-that-are-not-documents), you provide the sorting order as below:

```
{
  hobbies: ["dancing", "jogging"]
}
```

```
db.products.updateOne({"name": "ben"}, 
    {$push: {"hobbies": {$each: [], $sort: -1}}})
```

[Demo (Sorting non-documents in array) @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GL34-Vyykii)

When your elements in the array to be sorted are [documents](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#sort-array-of-documents-by-a-field-in-the-documents), you need to provide the field used to sort and the sorting order as below:

```
{
  hobbies: [
    { name: "dancing" }, 
    { name: "jogging" }
  ]
}
```

```
db.products.updateOne({"name": "ben"}, 
    {$push: {"hobbies": {$each: [], $sort: { name: -1 }}}})
```

[Demo (Sorting documents in array) @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X4Tk9p3EsPQ)

Comment: This is what I was trying to avoid with my question. I want a syntax - that does not involve **push** method.

Comment: It is kind of funny that the documentation and answer are provided, but you don't want this answer, you don't want that answer. So what's the point that you asked me to write the answer that you don't want it. If you don't want it, please provide more context in your question on what kind of the answer that you want. Thanks.